# How to get the intersection of two CGPath?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

I am using `CAShapeLayer.path` and `CALayer.mask` to set up image mask, i can achieve "difference set" and "union" effect for `CGPath` by setting

```
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd/kCAFillRuleZero
```

However, how can i get the intersection of two paths? I cannot achieve it with even-odd rule

Here is an example:
[image]

```
let view = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400))
view.image = UIImage(named: "scene.jpg")
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let maskPath = CGPathCreateMutable()    
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(maskPath, nil, CGRectOffset(CGRectInset(view.bounds, 50, 50), 50, 0))
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(maskPath, nil, CGRectOffset(CGRectInset(view.bounds, 50, 50), -50, 0))
maskLayer.path = maskPath
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
maskLayer.path = maskPath
view.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

how can i get the middle intersection area to be shown?

Comment: See http://robnapier.net/clipping-cgrect-cgpath for a technique. The same technique can be used for multiple CGPaths (it actually applies to anything you can draw).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
extension UIImage {

    func doubleCircleMask(diameter: CGFloat)-> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        let x = size.width/2 - diameter/2
        let y = size.height/2 - diameter/2
        let offset = diameter/4
        let bezierPath: UIBezierPath = .init(ovalIn: .init(origin: .init(x: x-offset, y: y), size: .init(width: diameter, height: diameter)))
        bezierPath.append(.init(ovalIn: .init(origin: .init(x: x+offset, y: y), size: .init(width: diameter, height: diameter))))
        bezierPath.addClip()
        draw(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }

    func doubleCircleIntersectionMask(diameter: CGFloat)-> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        let x = size.width/2 - diameter/2
        let y = size.height/2 - diameter/2
        let offset = diameter/4
        UIBezierPath(ovalIn: .init(origin: .init(x: x-offset, y: y), size: .init(width: diameter, height: diameter))).addClip()
        UIBezierPath(ovalIn: .init(origin: .init(x: x+offset, y: y), size: .init(width: diameter, height: diameter))).addClip()
        draw(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }

}
```

---

**Testing**

```
let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
let imageUnion = image.doubleCircleMask(diameter: 300)
let imageIntersection = image.doubleCircleIntersectionMask(diameter: 300)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, using `UIBezierPath` instead of `CGPath` make it possible to do multi-clip instead of being restricted by fillRule. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To be clear, this can also be done with `CGPath`s, so the comment about only `UIBezierPath`s making it possible is not accurate. Just check out this [Playground](https://gist.github.com/henrinormak/c6f792ed269723def347) I wrote using the same exact logic as in this answer, but using `CGContext` and `CGPath` instead